# Loop jQuery form post multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, post

I load an external php page in a `<div>` with a `$_POST`- form like this:

```
$("#tblStudents").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    var row_id = $("td:first a.ajaxCall", this).attr("rel");
    $("#ajaxContent").show().html("<div id='wait'></div>");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/pages/editstudent.php",
        data: {
            'student_id': row_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
        }
    });
});​
```

Now it seems that when I'm inside the `<div>` and do a form submit I can only do it once - then the script stop running. How can I edit my code to allow it multiple times? I guess I need to stop and start a function somewhere but where and how?

Comment: Have you checked for JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Does the data load and display the first time? Is the element `"#ajaxContext"` separate to your table (and not a parent of the table)?

Comment: Incidentally, the [jQuery .ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) say that if you don't specify a `type`, then it defaults to GET, not POST. Try using `$('#ajaxContent').load('/pages/editstudent.php',{'student_id':row_id})` [instead](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: forgive me for beeing stupid but I solved the problem myself. I had another script echoing out the status of the form submission and that element had a fadeout(4000). I was simply to fast on my submissions when I tested and didn't let the fadeout complete

Comment: then remove this question or add an answer and accept it (for the sake of the community) ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I had another script echoing out the status of the form submission and that element had a `fadeout(4000)`. I was simply to fast on my submissions when I tested and didn't let the fadeout complete

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tblStudents").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    var row_id = $("td:first a.ajaxCall", this).attr("rel");
    $("#ajaxContent").empty(); //empty first before appending to avoid append repitition 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/pages/editstudent.php",
        data: {
            'student_id': row_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#ajaxContent").append(data); //TRY TO USE OF .append() not .html() maybe 
        }
    });
});​
```